# How to handle recv() returning -1 from Browser on HTTP Server?

Tags: c, sockets, http, select, webserver

I am writing a small HTTP server on C, using select() and non-blocking sockets, but I have found myself with an issue.

When I accept a connection and try to read the HTTP Request (from a BROWSER, i.e: Mozilla Firefox) using the recv() function with 1024 length buffer. I get the whole request just fine. But in a general way, I don't know if recv() gave me the whole request or piece of it, meaning I don't know if I should keep reading or send a HTTP Response back to the client (BROWSER). What happens is as follows:

- I use recv(), so i get X bytes. (X could be less or equal to length of te request)
- I need to KNOW if there are more bytes or not to be read. So i check the return value of recv(). I´ve been debugging, and ultimately it returns the whole request on one recv() operation, but i am not sure if I should rely on that, that´s why I am concern.
- If the recv() operation where to return 0, it means the connection has been closed (shutdown), but BROWSER using persistent-connection won´t close the connection until recieving a HTTP Response.
- Therefore, recv returns -1 and errno is set to EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.

My question is, how to handle this case:

Will errno be set to EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK if the recv() function only read a piece of the request, or only if it has reached the end of the request and there is no more to be read?
How to handle that?

Thank you in advance
PS: I hope I´ve explained myself good enough so you can understand and try to help me.

Comment: Is this helpful?  http://www.binarytides.com/receive-full-data-with-recv-socket-function-in-c/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but didn´t quite answer my question. The problem is I don´t know if return value of -1 for the recv() function means that there was an actual Error or just that there is nothing else to read?

Comment: A return value of `-1` indicates an error, and `errno` will be set appropriately.

Comment: So, If I use recv() and get X bytes (the HTTP request has exactly X bytes) and then use recv() again (will return -1 setting EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK) (It is what is happening right now, cause the browser is waiting for a response) can I (as the programmer) assume that I should reply back?

Comment: I think you need to see @EJP's answer below.

Comment: I did, but not answering my question! Still stuck on it! I read that if the system buffer for the socket is full it will set errno to EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK, so, is it there another errno constant for to check and see if the peer on the other end of the socket sent the whole message that he has to be sent.

Comment: You didn't read that. You read that if it is *empty* it will set it to `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` on receiving. What you're describing is for sending. There is no other `errno`, nothing whatsoever that can tell you when a message is complete, because there are no messages in TCP. It is a byte-stream. You have to read and parse the HTTP request yourself. Only you can possibly know when it is complete. As I said in my answer, which *does* answer your question.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and now it did answer my question with "There are no messages in TCP, no associated errno". So I am going to try and parse the HTTP Request. However, when I send a request from a browser it doesn´t send the conten-length header, therefore maybe and I guess I should check for the CRLF at the end of the request? but that´s a matter for another question, If you know, let me know though. Marked as an accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will errno be set to EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK if the recv() function only read a piece of the request, or only if it has reached the end of the request and there is no more to be read? How to handle that?

Neither. It will be set to that value if there is no more data immediately available to be read. `recv()` doesn't know the HTTP request format from third base.

You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and friends to implement HTTP, specifically the parts about content-length and chunked encoding. You cannot do without it.

Comment: I know. And the HTTP specs I am using are very simple! Also, about chunked encoding: I think I don´t need to use it, cause I am parsing just GET requests from the browser to list a directory structure and or some files, ergo, my server will only "speak" small HTTP "vocabulary". Mainly, get the filename/dir path and reply back the content. Gonna use content-length thought. (I guess)

Comment: No guessing about it. You have to use it. And you have to read, complete, and parse the HTTP header yourself. TCP won't do that for you. It has no messages and no concept of HTTP.